# 0.3.2 boots into grub2

Tags: release-freya

So I installed Freya 0.3.2 and it works fine but every time I boot it goes into grub2 command line and I have to type "configfile /efi/grub/grub.cfg" and then select GNU/Linux to boot into Freya. Once I do that it works fine.

Would be much easier for me not to have to type that in every time I boot lol

Answer (score 1):

It seems like your grub configuration is wrong. Open the configuration with:

```
> sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Compare these lines with your configuration:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash"
```

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=”"`

```
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

If there're differences change them and save the file.

After that procedure update Grub with:

```
> sudo update-grub
```

Restart your computer and see the result.

Comment: The grub terminal=console line was missing so I added it, saved and then updated. Once I restarted it just booted into the blue UEFI key management  screen which I cannot get past.

Comment: "GRUB_TERMINAL=console" needs to be uncommented with "#" like above. Try this: "sudo apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi" and "sudo apt-get update-grub". Look here: [link](http://superuser.com/questions/376470/how-to-reinstall-grub2-efi)